# Arduino wireless options

Tags: c, macos, processing, wireless, arduino

I am currently working on a wireless solution for my Arduino and computer.  I am trying to connect a transmitter to my computer and a receiver to my Arduino.  I have seen a lot of examples with Arduino to Arduino communication but none for computer to Arduino.  What would I need to interface the transmitter with my computer, PIC?

Any insight or any links it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You already asked ten questions, never accepted an answer and never voted. I think it's time for you to understand how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [jeenode](http://shop.moderndevice.com/products/jeenode-kit) is a good low-cost solution.  It really depends on your needs, though.

Comment: doese jeenode act as both the receiver and transmitter?  So basically I would need two jeenodes, one with a USB-BUB board to connect to my computer and another connected to my arduino?  What I am basically trying to do is get rid of the usb cable with a wireless solution that isn't as expensive as xbee.

Comment: Yes.  Specifically, I have a [jeelink](http://shop.moderndevice.com/products/jeelink-module-fully-assembled) which is the whole thing in a USB fob.

Comment: So usb fob goes to pc and then a jeenode to arduino.  Sounds like a plan thanks

Answer (score 3):

Sparkfun has a [Wireless Buyers guide](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/128).  It's a couple of years old though.  There's also [this blog post](http://postscapes.com/arduino-wifi), which seems to be a pretty comprehensive survey of the available options.  It certainly listed every option I've ever heard of and several I'd never heard of before.

This [Freakduino board](http://www.freaklabsstore.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=22&products_id=187&zenid=5bhhnh4ldf9hd66b7150s9u6g5) looks interesting.  It's an Arduino clone with a built in IEEE 802.15.4 radio (the same radio in the Xbee's).  It's also priced very nicely.   I wish I'd known about it before I ordered my Arduino Uno earlier this week!

Answer (score 2):

You can use XBee from SparkFun.com.  I think they sell a kit for $70 or so.  I think they also have wifi solutions too.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could easily connect the two using a Bluetooth module. 
Sparkfun has a really good selection and tutorials on how to achieve what you want.
Worth a look in my opinion.
http://www.sparkfun.com/categories/115

Answer (score 0):

There is another interesting low power RF protocol called Ant+.  You can find more information at http://thisisant.com.